# Keeping database queries from ContentResolver and SQLiteDatabase from blocking each other

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

My app runs some very complicated queries using joins and other things which the Android ContentResolver is not equipped to handle. Some of these queries, inserts, etc can block the UI thread, so I run them in the background. As you might guess, this can cause a SQLiteException (database locked) when the timing of two sql requests coincide with one another (the most common cause of this is data loading into my db from our server in the background while the user requests to view data from the db on the screen).

The best way to fix this issue is to keep all DB activity on one thread, but like I said above some inserts in particular would cause some big time UI thread blockage, so that's not really realistic. The other option I've seen is synchronizing all the methods of the ContentResolver (they all should share a common member variable like a DatabaseHelper). I've done this, but again, this is not enough, because for some methods I have to use the SQLiteDatabase object's rawQuery() method to pull off the sql I need to get the data.

Is anyone aware of a strategy I could use to synchronize both ContentResolver methods and SQLiteDatabase methods? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would make the long inserts in a transaction

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

If you don't want that the requests that a user makes during the insert returns empty content, implement a logic of retry.

Would not this work ?